# How to prevent powershell merging msbuild properties?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have this powershell script

```
$msbuildSettings="/p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0";
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ..\Sol.sln /t:"Clean;Admin" $msbuildSettings
```

Which causes this error

```
The specified solution configuration "Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0|Mixed Platforms" is invalid.
```

Msbuild thinks

```
/p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

is one property.

If I do not use the variable msbuildsettings, the build works, i.e.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ..\WeConnectSol.sln /t:"Clean;WeConnectAdmin" /p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

How do I tell powershell not to *merge* the properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to use [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) and the `$env:windir` variable to determine the msbuild path:

```
$msbuild = Join-Path $env:windir 'Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe'
```

Also, I would use an array to define the parameters:

```
$parameters = @(
    '..\Sol.sln', 
    '/t:"Clean;Admin"', 
    '/p:Configuration=Release', 
    '/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0')
```

And finally pass the parameters using [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj672955.aspx):

```
& $msbuild @parameters
```